# Forgot bottle capper - priming interrupted

Tags: priming, capping, problems

I was all ready to bottle up my IPA last night (and yes, since this is StackExchange, I named the brew "IPAddress"). Everything got sanitized, bottles were de-labeled, the whole nine yards. I boil the priming sugar, pour it in, give it a stir, and it's looking lovely. I grab the first bottle, a cap, and....and where's the capper?

I spent the majority of last night turning my apartment over, looking for the dang thing. No dice - my best guess is I left it behind at my former apartment in a drawer. I re-airlocked the brew, having exhausted my options, and am going to purchase a new capper.

At this point, what are the effects on the finished beer going to be? Introducing more sugar is going to introduce more alcohol, and I have to wait until the yeast has chewed through everything I just introduced to it before attempting to prime it again. Am I freaking out unnecessarily?

Thanks for your help, and happy brewing!

Comment: so your bottle capper gave you a 404 - Not Found. ;) reloading the IPAddress with a new brows..capper should fix the issue! ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to worry! The priming sugar will up the alcohol content by a marginal amount but you probably won't notice. It is definitely a good idea to let the yeast take care of the extra priming sugar, although this shouldn't take too long, I'd say wait a couple days and then re-prime and bottle. Priming sugar is a pretty simple sugar so it should ferment quickly (also you don't add too much of it).

Just be careful, going through the bottling preparation process twice increases your chances of introducing an infection to your brew, but as long as you are mindful you should be fine!

Comment: +1 the sugar is consumed pretty quickly - easily within 24h. Priming sugar contributes around 0.2% alcohol for 2.4 volumes.

Comment: Bless your heart. I will stay the course! It looks like my coworkers will be enjoying a nice IPAddress sooner rather than later.